Try to Prove that at least one of $e^{e}$ or $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is transcendental, and whether it leads to something good.
(Assume we know that $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is irrational)
Proving that at least one of $e^{e}$ or $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is transcendental.
By contradiction, assume that $e^{e}$ and $\frac{\pi}{e}$ are algebraic.
$\frac{\pi}{e}$ is algebraic means $\frac{i\pi}{e}$ is algebraic, since the set of algebraic numbers forms field.
Now, $a=e^{e}$, and $b=\frac{i\pi}{e}$ are algebraic numbers satisfying Gelfond-Schneider Theorem Hypothesis (Remember, that I also assume that $\frac{i\pi}{e}$ is irrational ), then $a^{b}=-1$ is transcendental, which is contradiction.
So, we know that if $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is irrational, then at least one of $e^{e}$ or $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is transcendental.
My question, is the argument correct?, and does it have any benefit or just empty talk?

It is correct, but you don't need to assume that $\pi/e$ is irrational, since $i\pi/e$ is not real, so in particular it can't be rational

Some similar results appear in this post

@BrunoAndrades Yes you are right, thanks a lot, I have checked it from Ivan book, the requirement for $b$ that it is not a real rational number.

@lulu Thanks a lot for your kindness of sharing something related
